# Is There A Way To Auto-Stock Media Files To Every Site On A Wordpress Network?

Tags: media

I'm trying to find a way to upload images for everyone on my network to use, but I don't want sites sharing each other's media files. In other words, I want to stock sites with default media for them to use without having to do each site individually.

Does a way to do this exist?

Answer (score 0):

I found what I wanted: https://github.com/humanmade/network-media-library

Its works with the current release of Wordpress(5.1) at the time of this post, but is not found in Wordpress official plugin list. Alternative plugins with similar functionality at listed at the bottom of that page.